# Proving the identity $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{l} (2i)^{2}}{2} = \sum_{i=1}^{l} 2(l-i)^{2}$.

Tags: summation

In one of the lecture notes I have, there is an exercise in which I have to prove the following equality with sums:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{l} (2i)^{2}}{2} = \sum_{i=1}^{l} 2(l-i)^{2}. 
\end{equation}

**My approach:** \begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^{l} (2i)^{2} &= 2 \left( \sum_{i=1}^{l} 2(l-i)^{2} \right) \\
\sum_{i=1}^{l} 4i^{2} &= 2 \left( \sum_{i=1}^{l} 2(l^{2} -2li + i^{2}) \right) \\
\sum_{i=1}^{l} 4i^{2} &= 2 \left( \sum_{i=1}^{l} 2l^{2} -4li + 2i^{2}) \right) \\
\sum_{i=1}^{l} 4i^{2} &=  \sum_{i=1}^{l} 2(2(l^{2} -2li + i^{2})) \\
\sum_{i=1}^{l} 4i^{2} &=  \sum_{i=1}^{l} 4l^{2} -8li + 4i^{2}
\end{align*}

and from this point I have no idea how to continue-perhaps my approach is wrong.

Comment: The statement is wrong.

Comment: What is $n$?___

Comment: If $n=l+1$, just perform the substitution $j=l-i$.

Comment: This is true if and only if $n=l+1$, and in this case you can prove this by changing the index.

Comment: @AnneBauval  Sorry-my mistake: in the lecture notes it says that **$n=l$**. I edited the question.

Comment: The LHS is now greater than the RHS by $2l^2$. LHS=$2(1^2+2^2+…+l^2)$, RHS=$2(1^2+2^2+…+(l-1)^2)$.

Comment: You won't be able to prove this as the identity does not hold! E.g. put $l=1$. On the left, the sum is $2$, on the right it is $0$. As another example, for $l=2$, the sum on the left is $10$ whilst on the right you get $2$. Have you written down the expression incorrectly?

Comment: @MartinVaughan I have written the expression exactly as it is in the lecture notes-I will ask the professor.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Firstly, the identity needs correcting - the sum should be from $i=0$. If you take the sum from $i=1$, the identity does not hold. For example, put $l=1$, then

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{1}(2i)^{2} = 2
\end{equation}

whilst

\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^{1}2(l-i)^{2} = 0
\end{equation}

so no identity there! The original question obviously contains a typo.

What we need to *actually* prove (and which *is* an identity) is

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=0}^{l}(2i)^{2} \equiv \sum_{i=0}^{l}2(l-i)^{2}.
\end{equation}

We can take the factors of $2^{2}$ and $2$ outside the summations straight away, so we now have

\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=0}^{l}i^{2} = \sum_{i=0}^{l}(l-i)^{2}.
\end{equation}

**Edit**
Actually, as @DS points out in the comments, this already proves the case, since every term in the sum of $i^{2}$ appears in the sum over $(l-i)^{2}$. However, for a longer proof, multiply out the brackets on the right

\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=0}^{l}i^{2} = \sum_{i=0}^{l}(l^{2}-2li + i^{2}).
\end{equation}

The first term in the brackets is a constant, so remembering that we are summing from $i=0$ to $l$, this will get multiplied by a factor of $(l+1)$. That is

\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=0}^{l}l^{2} = (l+1)l^{2}.
\end{equation}

The second term involves the summation over $i$. I shall assume that you are familiar with the identity

\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=0}^{l}i = \frac{l(l+1)}{2}.
\end{equation}

Inserting these results into the expression above, we now have

\begin{align}
\sum_{i=0}^{l}i^{2} &= l^{2}(l+1) - 2l\frac{l(l+1)}{2} + \sum_{i=0}^{l}i^{2} \\
&= \sum_{i=0}^{l}i^{2},
\end{align}

as required.

Since we have now proved

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=0}^{l}(2i)^{2} \equiv \sum_{i=0}^{l}2(l-i)^{2},
\end{equation}

it is easy to show explicitly why

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{l}(2i)^{2} \not\equiv \sum_{i=1}^{l}2(l-i)^{2},
\end{equation}

since

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=0}^{l}(2i)^{2} \equiv \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{l}(2i)^{2}
\end{equation}

but

\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^{l}2(l-i)^{2} &\equiv \sum_{i=0}^{l}2(l-i)^{2} - 2l^{2} \\
&\not\equiv \sum_{i=0}^{l}2(l-i)^{2}.
\end{align}

Hence the original expression is incorrect.

Comment: $\sum_{i=0}^{l}i^{2} = \sum_{i=0}^{l}(l-i)^{2}$ is obvious reindexing. You have done too much after that.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that - the identity as written in the question is incorrect (there is obviously a typo). One has to put the sum from $i=0$ for the identity to hold. Thereafter, I have just shown how to prove it. What is your objection to that?

Comment: First, I haven't downvoted, and I have no "objection" per se. I was just noting that the equation after "outside the summations straight away, so we now have" is just a reindexing of the sum, and everything you've done after that is a painfully long method.

Comment: Fair enough! I missed the point you were making.